# Param with blank value triggers (!isset) validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postman, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

Here is my script:-

```
if (!isset($request->security_token)) 
{ 
    // Provide security token
    $error = TRUE;
    $err_message[] = Lang::get('caption_validation_error.ser_valid_security_token.value');
    $err_validation[] = Lang::get('caption_validation_error.ser_valid_security_token.value').' [security_token]';
}
```

It means, if a param is not "sent", then the validation will be triggered. However, if a param with "blank" value is sent, it must not trigger the validation.

However, when I am hitting the api through POSTMAN app, the security_token with blank value enters the !isset validation.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just checking and it might seem daft but are you sure they are params? If you use the `Params` feature, they should be showing in the URL right? Those look like request `Headers`. I can't see the top part in the image so hence the silly question.

Comment: They are form-data params. Do you see the body tag being highlighted?

Comment: Not on the image - I see the response body highlighted not the request body. That's been cut off due to the scrolling, kinda why I asked the question. Might need to add that to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not that obvious why it's like this because it seems quite strange at first glance. However if you know a bit more about Laravel and you look at `app/Http/Kernel.php` file you will see in there:

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
```

which as you can find out from name converts empty strings to null. So in your case when you are sending empty parameter it's considered as `null` so `!isset($null)` will be true.

So you have 2 options:

1. remove this middleware from array - however it will affect the whole application so it might not be the best way if you are not sure about it
2. Assuming you want to trigger this validation only if parameter is not sent at all instead of

   ```
   if (!isset($request->security_token))
   ```

   you can use for example

   ```
   if (!$request->has('security_token'))
   ```

   Obviously it's not exactly the same - if you now sent this token and set it to `null` it won't be still executed but I believe when you now know what's happening with this empty string you can now adjust it exactly to your needs.